# Yolo V8 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, yolo

I am trying to localise my robot using a camera. After months trying to use classical computer vision to pinpoint landmarks in my garden I gave up and created a custom dataset and quickly trained a yolov8 nano model which was outstandingly effective. Now I have just got to work on speed.
I ran the following code to see the effect of image size:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import cv2

from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO("best.pt")  # load a pretrained model (recommended for     training)

img = cv2.imread('house.jpg')


sizes = [320,480,640,1280]

for sz in sizes:
   times = []
   resized = cv2.resize(img, (sz,sz), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
for i in range(10):
    timeStart = time.time()
    results = model.predict(source= resized,show= False,verbose = False)  # predict on an image
    timeEnd = time.time()
    times.append(timeEnd-timeStart)
ar = np.array(times)
print(f'size:{sz:4}, mean:{int(ar.mean()*1000):3}, st dev:{int(ar.std()*1000):3}, min:{int(ar.min()*1000):3}, max:{int(ar.max()*1000)}:3')
```

The results on my laptop which has an i9 processor and a small GPU are:

size: 320, mean: 19, st dev: 16, min: 10, max:134

size: 480, mean: 16, st dev:  4, min:  6, max: 31

size: 640, mean: 15, st dev:  4, min: 10, max: 20

size:1280, mean: 16, st dev:  4, min:  8, max: 30

all times are milliseconds

I did not expect much difference as I assumed that they would all fit on the GPU and be done in parallel. Clearly however the smaller size takes longer but i think for someunkown reason it simply the first to be done that is slower, perhaps loading weights.
To an extent the results on the laptop are academic - they are very fast, however the results on the RPI 4 are another story. Using the same piece of code:

size: 320, mean:2002, st dev:391, min:1846, max:3177

size: 480, mean:1895, st dev:26, min:1845, max:1929

size: 640, mean:1933, st dev:30, min:1902, max:1992

size:1280, mean:1931, st dev:33, min:1896, max:1991

Again the first size is slower and all sizes are depressingly slow.

I had expected/hoped that reducing the size on the CPU would have speeded things up.
Soo my questions are why are smaller sizes not faster on a CPU and what if anything can I do to speed things up. I tried overclocking to 1800 and this produced an insignificant speedup?

Answer (score 2):

> why are smaller sizes not faster on a CPU

I've rerun your code and find that the result is unstable. However, when I increase the for-loop to 100 runs, the result is more stable and reasonable.

I don't think yolov8-nano yeilds significantly different latency on high-end CPU, since it's very lightweight.

I think your result on Pi 4 has the same problem of stability. However, the difference are clearer.

> what if anything can I do to speed things up

I don't think overclocking is a good idea for Pi 4. Have you tried converting into ONNX to use with ONNXRuntime? If it doesn't improve, then convert ONNX model into NCNN. In my experience, it can reduce 20-50% latency.

Cortex A72 on Pi 4 is not a very strong CPU. In general, Raspberry Pi is not designed to run deep learning models. Your raw result (2s/image) is quite the same as my test, so you should not expect too much about it :)

Besides, can you tell more about your interesting project so that the community can give you more effective solutions?

Comment: will have a look at your suggestions re ONNX and NCNN. I knew the RPi would be slow that is why using a neural model was my last option.